# Nexus hangs on startup

Tags: java, maven, nexus

After a boot of the Linux server I can no longer start [Nexus Repository Manager](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/go/).

It runs on Tomcat 7.

Last line from `catalina.out` is:

```
2014-12-05 11:31:34 INFO  [maven.zigmaqq.org-startStop-1] - org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.ConfigurationBuilder -   security-xml-file='/apps/nexus/sonatype-work/nexus/conf/security.xml'
```

I've seen this before. Previously I have been able to kill Tomcat and then restart and that would fix it.

What happens is that the startup simply hangs. When looking from the side of Linux the Tomcat process uses no CPU.

For comparison this is what a normal startup looks like:

```
2014-10-26 10:23:53 INFO  [maven.zigmaqq.org-startStop-1] - org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.ConfigurationBuilder -   security-xml-file='/apps/nexus/sonatype-work/nexus/conf/security.xml'
2014-10-26 10:23:57 INFO  [maven.zigmaqq.org-startStop-1] - org.sonatype.nexus.webapp.metrics.MetricsModule - Metrics support configured
2014-10-26 10:24:02 INFO  [maven.zigmaqq.org-startStop-1] - org.sonatype.sisu.goodies.eventbus.internal.DefaultEventBus - Using Reentrant Guava EventBus
2014-10-26 10:24:02 INFO  [maven.zigmaqq.org-startStop-1] - org.sonatype.security.configuration.source.FileSecurityConfigurationSource - Loading Security configuration from /apps/nexus/sonatype-work/nexus/conf/security-configuration.xml
2014-10-26 10:24:02 INFO  [maven.zigmaqq.org-startStop-1] - org.sonatype.sisu.ehcache.CacheManagerComponentImpl - Loading configuration from: file:/apps/tomcat/base/webapps/maven/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/ehcache.xml
2014-10-26 10:24:03 INFO  [maven.zigmaqq.org-startStop-1] - com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream - Version: 1.4.6-SONATYPE-02, white-list support available
2014-10-26 10:24:03 INFO  [maven.zigmaqq.org-startStop-1] - org.sonatype.nexus.proxy.registry.DefaultRepositoryTypeRegistry - Registered default repository types.
2014-10-26 10:24:03 INFO  [com-startStop-1] - org.sonatype.nexus.events.EventSubscriberHost - Initialized
2014-10-26 10:24:03 INFO  [com-startStop-1] - org.sonatype.nexus.NxApplication -
-------------------------------------------------

Initializing Sonatype Nexus 2.8.0-05

-------------------------------------------------
2014-10-26 10:24:03 INFO  [com-startStop-1] - org.sonatype.nexus.NxApplication - Activating locally installed plugins...
2014-10-26 10:25:00 INFO  [com-startStop-1] - org.sonatype.nexus.kazuki.KazukiPlugin - Kazuki version: 0.1.8
2014-10-26 10:25:09 INFO  [com-startStop-1] - org.sonatype.nexus.proxy.registry.DefaultRepositoryTypeRegistry - Registered Repository type RepositoryType=(org.sonatype.nexus.proxy.repository.WebSiteRepository:site).
2014-10-26 10:25:11 INFO  [com-startStop-1] - org.sonatype.nexus.NxApplication - Plugin manager request "ACTIVATE" on plugin "org.sonatype.nexus.plugins:nexus-rrb-plugin:2.8.0-05" was successful.
.....
.....
```

I've tried upgrading to latest and greatest, Nexus OSS v2.11. Still no luck.

Is there some switch I can throw that will debug this problem to a greater detail?

Thanks

### UPDATE

As previously I was now able to start Nexus again after some attempts. (*without* changing anything in the environment). So the problem is now over .. until it happens again. I'm guessing there's some kind of race condition.

I followed the instructions [here](https://support.sonatype.com/entries/25427167-Nexus-Logging-Guide) for how increase log level. While it does produce a lot of extra output it doesn't actually produce extra output *between* the two events that I'm interested in (see above log output). So it didn't make me any wiser.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove `sonatype-work/nexus/nexus.lock` file.

Comment: This is long time ago and have upgraded Nexus several times since then to newer versions and haven't seen the problem since way back. Still I believe your "guess" (and proposed solution) is as good as anyone and I don't understand why you got a downvote.

Answer (score -1):

If this happens again get a thread dump and put it on a NEXUS issue at https://issues.sonatype.org.

https://support.sonatype.com/entries/24531752-Nexus-Thread-Dump-and-Heap-Dump-Guide